# Create empty array of length n

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Pretty basic question but does anyone know how to create an empty array in Google Apps Script with a defined integer length `n`. Tried `new array(n)` but don't think its part of the Google Apps Script spec.

I know I can do it with with a loop (or manually typing it out) but wondered if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try `new Array(n)` with a capital A?

```
function makeArray() {
  var a = new Array(5);
  Logger.log(a);
};
```